# Replace multiple classes onScroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a [horizontal website](https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY) this week and received lots of advice and helpful code from the community here (thanks!).

My JS skills are very shaky but I'm picking it up better, my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/xvgBvY) shows what I have just now, and its working more or less perfectly. I've combined two separate functions to help the onClick work, but this obviously does not work onScroll also. I am trying to understand what the best practice for this is as I still don't understand the rules of JS fully.

Problem: `onScroll` the `active` class activates fine (turns yellow), but the `ion-ios-radio-button-on` does not switch to `ion-ios-radio-button-off` (and vice versa). However, if you click on the icons they will change fully.

I have tried messing around with what's there, such as adding more replace/add/remove properties, but of course they probably would not work as I am unsure where to place them. I know this code can be condensed too, but my skill level is not that advanced.

Any advice and help to broaden my knowledge is appreciated as always!

```js
// ---

const main = document.querySelector( 'main' );
const nav = document.querySelector( '.bottomnav' );
const setIconState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state ?
    icon.className.replace('button-off', 'button-on') :
    icon.className.replace('button-on', 'button-off')

const toggleIcon = element => {
    const className = element.className;
    element.className = className.indexOf('button-on') > -1 ?
        setIconState(element, false) :
        setIconState(element, true);
}

const setIconActiveState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state ?
    icon.className = `${icon.className} active` :
    icon.className = icon.className.replace('active', '')

document.querySelectorAll('.bottomnav a.icon')
    .forEach(icon => {
        icon.onclick = (e) => {
            const {
                target: clickedSpan
            } = e;

            const siblings = [...clickedSpan.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('a.icon')]
                .filter(sibling => sibling != clickedSpan);

            siblings.forEach(icon => {
                setIconState(icon, false);
                setIconActiveState(icon, false);
            });
            setIconState(clickedSpan, true);
            setIconActiveState(clickedSpan, true);
        };
    });

let scrollend;

function onwheel(){
  
/* When using the scrollwheel, translate Y direction scrolls to X direction. This way scrollwheel users get the benefit of scrolling down to go right, while touch and other users get default behaviour. */
  
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
  main.scrollLeft += event.wheelDeltaY;
  
}
function onscroll(){
  
  const current = Array.from( main.children ).find(child => {
  
      return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;
      
  });
  const link = Array.from( nav.children ).reduce((find, child) => {
    
    child.classList.remove( 'active' );
    
    return find || (child.href.indexOf( current.id ) >= 0 ? child : find);
    
  }, false);
  
  if( link ) link.classList.add( 'active' );
  
  clearTimeout( scrollend );
  scrollend = setTimeout( onscrollend, 100 );
  
}
function onscrollend(){
  
  /* After scrolling ends, snap the appropriate element. This could be done with an animation. */
  clearTimeout( scrollend );
  
  const current = Array.from( main.children ).find(child => {
  
      return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;
      
  });
  
  main.scrollLeft = current.offsetLeft;
  
}

/* Bind and initial call */

main.addEventListener( 'wheel', onwheel );
main.addEventListener( 'scroll', onscroll );

onscroll();
```

```css
html,
body,
main {
    height: 100%;
  scoll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
main section {
  padding: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.bottomnav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.bottomnav a {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 26px;
/*     color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%; */
}

.bottomnav a:hover {
      color: #fac123;
    transition: color .5s;
}

.bottomnav a.active {
    color: #fac123;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.card {
  height: 100vh;
}

.cardblack {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="bottomnav">
  
   <a href="#1" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#2" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#3" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off">Section 3</a>
        </div>
<main>
<section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
   </section>
   
   <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
   </section>
   
   <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
   </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can call the same code as was called in the on click:

```js
  setIconState(link, true);
  setIconActiveState(link, true);
```

So you can remove:

```js
  if (link) link.classList.add('active');
```

Does that do the trick?

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const nav = document.querySelector('.bottomnav');

const setIconState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state ?
  icon.className.replace('button-off', 'button-on') :
  icon.className.replace('button-on', 'button-off')

const toggleIcon = element => {
  const className = element.className;
  element.className = className.indexOf('button-on') > -1 ?
    setIconState(element, false) :
    setIconState(element, true);
}

const setIconActiveState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state ?
  icon.className = `${icon.className} active` :
  icon.className = icon.className.replace('active', '')

document.querySelectorAll('.bottomnav a.icon')
  .forEach(icon => {
    icon.onclick = (e) => {
      const {
        target: clickedSpan
      } = e;

      const siblings = [...clickedSpan.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('a.icon')]
        .filter(sibling => sibling != clickedSpan);

      siblings.forEach(icon => {
        setIconState(icon, false);
        setIconActiveState(icon, false);
      });
      setIconState(clickedSpan, true);
      setIconActiveState(clickedSpan, true);
    };
  });

let scrollend;

function onwheel() {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();

  main.scrollLeft += event.wheelDeltaY;
}

function onscroll() {
  const current = Array.from(main.children).find(child => {

    return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;

  });
  
  const link = Array.from(nav.children).reduce((find, child) => {
    child.classList.remove('active');

    return find || (child.href.indexOf(current.id) >= 0 ? child : find);
  }, false);

  setIconState(link, true);
  setIconActiveState(link, true);

  clearTimeout(scrollend);
  scrollend = setTimeout(onscrollend, 100);
}

function onscrollend() {

  /* After scrolling ends, snap the appropriate element. This could be done with an animation. */
  clearTimeout(scrollend);

  const current = Array.from(main.children).find(child => {

    return child.offsetLeft >= main.scrollLeft - innerWidth / 2;

  });

  main.scrollLeft = current.offsetLeft;

}

/* Bind and initial call */

main.addEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
main.addEventListener('scroll', onscroll);

onscroll();
```

```css
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
  scoll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

main section {
  padding: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.bottomnav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottomnav a {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 26px;
  /*     color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%; */
}

.bottomnav a:hover {
  color: #fac123;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.bottomnav a.active {
  color: #fac123;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.card {
  height: 100vh;
}

.cardblack {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="bottomnav">
  <a href="#1" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#2" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#3" class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off">Section 3</a>
</div>

<main>
  <section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
  </section>

  <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
  </section>

  <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```